# Objects within Objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to setup a constants file for one of my sites. I am trying to set it up so I can get string constants when needed.

What I have so far (Not working, kind of C# ish)

```
var Constants = new SiteConstants();

function SiteConstants()
{
    this.Training = function Training()
    {
        this.Staff = function Staff()
        {
            this.fetch = "someurl";
        }
    }
}

console.log(Constants.Training().Staff().fetch); //Fail - what i want to call
//or something similar like Constants.Training.Staff.fetch
console.log((new Constants.Staff()).fetch); //Success
```

Is this possible in JavaScript, and if not, can someone suggest an alternative?

Comment: since they are constructors, `(new (new Constants.Training()).Staff()).fetch`

Comment: Constants _per se_ do not exist in Javascript. If you are trying to create objects in other objects, just use object literal notation and assignment as appropriate.

Comment: @K.Hallman While you are right, there is the `const` keyword (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) but I wouldn't suggest it since it isn't widely supported yet. And I think it's pretty obvious what the OP means by "constants", and object literals, as you suggest, are probably the best way to go...

Comment: @Ian `const` is a reserved word but not presently implemented in the ECMAScript spec, to my knowledge. The OP was confusing because it used a word that has a specific meaning in an unclear way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use objects instead of functions for this purpose.

```
var Constants = {
    Training: {
        Staff: {
            fetch: "someurl"
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to define each constructor properly.

```
function SiteConstants()
{
  this.training = new Training();
}

function Training()
{
  this.staff = new Staff();
}

function Staff()
{
  this.fetch = "someurl";
}
```

Or you can also do it like this:

```
function SiteConstants()
{
    function Training()
    {
        function Staff()
        {
            this.fetch = "someurl";
        }

        this.Staff = new Staff();
    }

    this.Training = new Training();
}
```

Comment: I needed to have them enclosed, so that there would be no conflicting objects (We have a ton of javascript objects on our site)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest an entirely different approach; one that is more idiomatic to JavaScript: JSON.

```
{
    "siteConstants" : {
        "training" : {
            "staff" : {
                "fetch" : "someurl"
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Then, if you have this object attached to `var constantsObject`, you can access the constants as such:

```
constantsObject.siteConstants.training.staff.fetch;    // returns "someurl"
constantsObject["siteConstants"]["training"]["staff"]["fetch"] // returns "someurl"
```

Comment: There's no "JSON" type in JavaScript. You're creating an object literal, which another answer has already provided

Comment: @Ian I never called it a type. I said "approach."

Comment: I still don't see why JSON should even be referenced here. JSON is a data transfer format, and has nothing to do with JavaScript (other than the fact that it was derived from JS objects)

Comment: @Ian  Also, I hadn't seen Anton L's answer until after I had posted mine. Regardless, JSON could be used externally, which would probably serve the OP's request better: `"I am trying to setup a constants file for one of my sites."`

Answer (score 1):

You are defining Training as a constructor but never actually invoking it. What you want is:

```
function SiteConstants()
{
    var Training = function Training() //constructor
    {
        this.Staff = function Staff()
        {
            this.fetch = "someurl";
        }
    }
    this.Training = new Training();
}
```

And so on for the inner class.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a new object like this

```
var Obj = new Constants.Training();
```

then you need to call the function Staff and `console.log` the `Obj.fetch`

```
Obj.Staff();
console.log(Obj.fetch);
```

or you can do this

```
function SiteConstants()
{
    this.Training = function Training()
    {
        this.Staff = function Staff()
        {
            this.fetch = "someurl";
        }
    }
}
var Constants = new SiteConstants();
Constants.Training = new Constants.Training();
Constants.Training.Staff();
console.log(Constants.Training.fetch);
```